Unde urbem licet aestimare totam?
Martial (4.64, 11–12) famously wrote:

Hinc septem dominos videre montis
Et totam licet aestimare Romam

This refers to a view from the Ianiculum on the west bank of Tiber.
How precisely do we know where he looked from?
The Finnish Institute in Rome is in Villa Lante, a Renaissance villa on Gianicolo, at Passeggiata del Gianicolo 10.
The balcony has a splendid view over Rome, and they have an abbreviated version of Martial inscribed on its wall:

This got me curious:
How close is Villa Lante to the site whose views Martial praises?
Assuming it was on top of the hill, it can't have been much more than 200 meters off.
I have never heard anyone mention whether Martial referred to the views from exactly the same spot or just from the same hill.
(I adapted the question title a bit so it's a question and scans right.)

The first line: "From here to see the seven lords of the mountain,", the seven lords (of Rome) are the seven hills; but what is "the mountain"?

@tony Here montis is the plural accusative, not the singular genitive. He sees "the seven majestic mountains" or something along those lines.
